# Разработка php (средства)

Tags: php

Думаю, что вопрос несколько расходится с правилами проекта, но тем не менее прошу администрацию не удалять вопрос. Вопрос будет закрыт ровно через неделю. Надеюсь, что ответы окажутся полезными как новичкам так и тем, кто уже давно занимается разработкой на PHP.

Исходя из своего опыта разработки на php я менял IDE, платформы(сервер со всем необходимым фаршем), по разному размещал исходники. Я остановился на не очень обычном варианте с костылями, который тем не менее полностью покрывает мои потребности.

Хотелось бы поинтересоваться, а кто чем пользуется? Просьба обязательно укажите следующую информацию:

- какие у вас были потребности к ПО для разработки на PHP,
- какую IDE и платформу(фарш с сервером) вы используете,
- если были нестандартные задачи укажите, как вы их реализовали.

**Обновление**

Хотелось бы поднять тему последний раз перед ее закрытием и прочитать побольше новых ответов.

Меня сильно удивило, что никто не отписался насчет платформы с использованием Git или SVN, или же чего либо мне еще не известного. Все еще надеюсь на интересные и необычные варианты рабочего окружения для разработки под PHP.

Так же хочу поздравить всех с наступающим праздником.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IDE

PHPStorm, конечно. На самом деле меня уже пугает эта монополия, потому что многие плюшки завязаны на него одного, и при переходе на что-нибудь другое куча времени уйдет не на переобучение, а просто на пересоздание функционала. Из рюшечек, которые используются не так часто:

- File Watcher + Codeception + промежуточный shell-скрипт (если есть tests/Unit/$файл$Test.php - прогнать его) = автотесты, которые упадут с ошибкой в случае чего. Не сказать, что спасло меня хоть раз, но сознание приятно будоражит
- Стек run configurations - почти что ci-джоба. Можно настроить себе всё тестирование и анализ одним стеком и запускать за час до конца рабочего дня.
- Запуск тех же конфигураций в режиме отладки позволяет залезть прямо в тест и посмотреть, что упало. По-хорошему так делать нельзя, по-хорошему надо делать такие отчеты для тестов, чтобы в них можно было установить первопричину падения, но у нас же никогда нет времени.
- Подключение coverage.xml и подсветка еще не покрытых строк.
- Рефакторинг - абсолютно божественная штука
- Кодогенерация (alt + insert) - как правило, использую только для геттеров/сеттеров и все равно парвлю PHPDoc, но очень уж приятная штука
- Не знаю как в других IDE, но в PHPStorm довольно приятная поддержка неймспейсов
- Интеграция PHPMD/PHPCS прямо на уровне подсветки кислых строк.
- Проверка файлов перед коммитом - очень полезная штука, хоть я и могу ее нормально использовать только в своих проектах (времени, к сожалению, не хватает на работе).

Веб-сервер

nginx. До сих пор свободно не ориентируюсь в конфигах, но с ним как-то легче, чем с апачем (гори в аду, .htaccess) + в 99% случаев на продакшене будет именно он. PHP-FPM настроен на три конфигурации - dev, test, prod, но ни разу это серьезного буста не придало. Конфигурирую руками, что неправильно примерно на все 100% - я до сих пор не знаю, как это должно быть в идеале (vagrant? docker? virtualbox + chef/puppet/saltstack?), но руками это дело делать нельзя. В свое время была идея написать простенький консольный конфигуратор веб-сервера, но проект успешно заглох - чтобы реализовать его полностью, мне нужно сначала дописать еще пару либ, которые благополучно стоят на месте.

OS

Linux Mint / KDE. Просто личное предпочтение. Ну, на самом деле на домашнем стационарнике по ряду причин винда 8, но в виртуалке - Linux Mint. By the way - собственное окружение также стоит организовывать через какой-нибудь puppet, потому что очень болезненно все накатывать в пятый раз вручную.

Расположение исходников

Я по-своему долбанутый, поэтому держу такую структуру:

- /srv/http/src - реальные сорцы веб-проектов
- /srv/http/hosts - симлинки на сорцы по названиям хостов (например, в сорцах может валяться проект playground, а в хостах - playground.dev, admin.playground.dev, special.playground.dev)
- /srv/http/apps - всякие pma, которыми я прекратил пользоваться
- /home/etki/Workspace - папки с симлинками на сорцы + собственные проекты, которые не требуют веб-сервера (библиотеки)
- /usr/local/bin/composer - композер
- /usr/local/composer - глобальная папка композера
- /var/cache/composer - кэш композера. Вкупе с предпоследней папкой превращают глобальную видимость композера из user-wide в system-wide
- /usr/local/composer/vendor/bin - добавляется в PATH

У нормальных людей вместо /srv/http используется /var/www

хосты организую с помощью dnsmasq (просто добавил резолв в 127.0.0.1 для tld loc, local, dev, prod, test)

Библиотеки, фреймворки и утилиты

В ходе последних месяцев было установлено следующее:

- Для PHP есть порядочно клевых утилит для тестинга и анализа кода - уже упомянутые phpcs и phpmd, phpcpd, phpdcd, php docblock checker (это для таких зануд, как я), parallel lint, pdepend, phploc, которые многое могут сказать о коде. php-cs-fixer вам еще и поправит код. Конкретно для тестинга - athletic, codeception, первый по понятным причинам используется редко, но когда его удается применить, радуюсь, как ребенок.
- Opencart, Yii, Yii2, CI, Kohana, Wordpress, Joomla - лютое, непробиваемое, которое нельзя использовать никогда. Yii2 - разочарование года, казалось бы, все костыли уже известны, но все равно там на каждом шагу какие-то грабли.
- Прямо сейчас стоит проект, которому открутить бы Yii и подставить Symfony. Это уже невозможно, но если бы я делал миграции на Phinx (а я же умею, блин) и изначально писал более портабельный код, я бы таки смог перепрыгнуть между итерациями за эти новогодние праздники.
- Любая апишка должна писаться через guzzle. Это банально отбивается по времени. Кроме того, mock plugin на раз-два позволяет вторгнуться в ход выполнения и подсунуть свой ответ, что позволяет разрабатывать клиента апишки, не трогая саму апишку. Еще один гвоздь в текущий проект.
- На packagist лежит несколько пакетов виртуальной файловой системы. Потребуется время, чтобы в них вникнуть, но с этой штукой можно тестирование прямо взлетает на новый уровень.
- Mock (неважно, от какой из библиотек, PHPUnit, Mockery, Codeception/Stub) - лучшее изобретение человечества. Это опять упирается в мой любимый тестинг, но когда я наконец начал использовать всю связку этих волшебных практик, я наконец-то понял, как и зачем пишется несвязный код (и почему отвратительнее богообъекта Yii не может быть ничего).
- Везде, где нет шаблонизатора или есть выбор, лучше использовать Twig. Он и руками прикручивается строчек за пять кода, и снимает большинство головной боли - хочешь, наследуй шаблоны, хочешь, реализуй привычную layout-систему.

Практики написания кода

- Статичные методы действительно нельзя использовать. Потому что если конкретный объект еще можно подменить, то статичный вызов всегда зависит от имени класса, что намертво вбивает зависимость в код. Это уже и не оттестить, и не отрефакторить в короткие сроки. Можно, конечно, использовать `$className::method()`, но лично у меня от такого глаза на лоб лезут. Любой простенький контейнер позволит вам проинициализировать объекты один раз и быть уверенным в производительности кода.
- ВСЕГДА, ВСЕГДА реализовывать поддержку dev / prod / test окружения, даже если этого нет в фреймворке. Когда проект раздувается до десятка апишек, внедрять эту штуку уже поздно, потому что все излишки уходят на быстрый (а значит, плохой) рефакторинг.
- Всегда, когда это возможно, должна вводиться поддержка feature flags и dev traits (по большому счету, это одно и то же, dev traits я вообще сам для себя выдумал). Feature flags - это просто набор флагов (булевых значений) в конфигурации, который управляет тем, включены или выключены определенные фичи. Это позволяет включать и выключать фичи мановением руки, и в деве фича может нестабильно, но работать, а в проде быть выключена вообще. Или работать стабильно, но ожидать ревью от отдела тестирования. Dev traits - это тоже набор флагов, который работает только в dev-окружении и управляет дополнительным поведением приложения, облегчающим разработку: заполняет формы, скрывает элементы и т.п. В моем текущем проекте эта штука спасла меня, когда пришлось переводить гигантский лендинг - я научил компонент перевода подкрашивать токены разным цветом в зависимости от того переведены они, или нет, а вместо пустых вызовов ставить красную заглушку об отсутствии токена. Еще один флаг позволяет скрыть перевод вообще к чертям, что позволяет мне увидеть только непереведенный текст.
- Ни один конфиг на свете не должен писаться на PHP (привет еще раз, Yii!). Это просто отвратительно, такой конфиг невозможно толкого записать в файл еще раз. Даже если восстановить структуру массива, потеряются все выражения и инклюды. Один из моих ожидающих свободного времени сайд-проектов - это конфигуратор на основе yaml, который поддерживает простенькие expression'ы типа `!include file.yaml` / `!realpath src` / `!instantiate \Vendor\Lib\Class`, который наконец позволит мне комфортно работать с Yii (ну а с чем же еще).
- Я выше уже писал про миграции - на любом проекте, который не использует разворачиваемую из коробки структру бд, они должны использоваться; любой шаг в сторону карается насквозь простреленной ногой. Я как-то спрашивал, насколько атомарны должны быть миграции - ну так вот, они должны быть максимально атомарны, одно изменение - одна миграция. Когда в одной миграции создается таблица, а затем последующее создание foreign key проваливается - это простреливает и вторую ногу. Плюс вообще все мигарции должны писаться с расчетом на присутствие данных - вы не сможете сделать столбец уникальным, если там уже висят неуникальные значения.
- Interfaces first: везде, где предполагаются *имплементации*, все должно зависеть от интерфейсов. Это довольно тонкий момент, на вербализацию которого у меня не хватит способностей, но если вкратце на примере: клиент апишки должен обрабатывать не `HttpResponse`, а `HttpResponseInterface`. В этом случае смена библиотеки, осуществляющей сетевые запросы превращается из перекапывания всех уровней написанного кода в написание тривиального враппера, который будет удовлетворять требованиям `HttpResponseInterface`. Насколько понимаю, именно это и есть D в SOLID. Ну и согласно I - ни один интерфейс не должен вбирать в себя миллион методов. Пока я не узнал про мок-плагин для guzzle, я собирался писать аналогичный функционал, который бы обходил guzzle целиком и возвращал бы `ResponseInterface`-объект (простого мока тут явно не хватило бы). Когда я увидел, что там придется реализовывать порядка пятнадцати методов, о 70% которых я не имею ни малейшего представления - мне порядком взгрустнулось.
- Как правило, любой проект практически заставляет писать свои исключения. В этом случае есть очень полезный хак, который позволяет установить обработчик исключений только на исключения данной библиотеки, и при этом сохранить традиционную цепочку наследования. Делается это так:

  - Пишется пустой интерфейс

    ```
    interface MahSuperLibExceptionInterfce {}
    ```
  - Наследуются все стандартные исключения SPL c включением этого интерфейса

    ```
    namespace Vendor\MahSuperLib\Exception;

    use LogicException as SplLogicException;

    class LogicException extends SplLogicException implements MahSuperLibExceptionInterface {}
    ```
  - Нестандартные исключения наследуются от созданных в предыдущем пункте
  - После этого любому обработчику достаточно ловить интерфейс, чтобы отловить только исключения только этой либы/проекта:

    ```
    try {
        // ...
    } catch (MahSuperLibExceptionInterface $e) {
        // hehe
    }
    ```
- И ссылка на довольно крутой, хоть и лаконичный пдф http://www.planetgeek.ch/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Clean-Code-V2.4.pdf

И еще немного

Я не знаю как (у меня практически по минутам все расписано до конца января минимум), но в ближайшее время подниму себе стек jenkins + агенты на докере + selenium + phantom + sonarqube. Все предыдущее просто меркнет после того, как эта цепочка настроена. Jenkins позволит прогнать любые тесты приложения, а Sonarqube - это такой божественный сервер статанализа кода, который сам посчитыаеттехнический долг и выдаст, сколько его рефакторить. Проще один раз [показать](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/), посмотрите, это невероятное творение, умеет работать со всеми основными языками.

Пока что сижу на travis и codeship, планирую еще попробовать shippable. Ну и еще существует миллиард полезных сервисов (scrutinizer, versioneye, codeclimate), до которых просто руки не доходят.

простите за сумбурное изложение, позже может еще пару правок вкачу.

Comment: я думаю, Вам  это нужно в отдельную статью оформить. Полезный "экспириенс"

Comment: @barseon, у меня манускрипт по тестированию с сентября стоит :\

Comment: и не лень же было столько писать...

Answer (score 2):

Для Php на мой взгляд идеально подходит PhpStorm IDE. Во-всяком случае много чего перепробовал, лучше не нашлось.

Использую ОС Debian Linux по ряду причин (даже не по причине резкой неприязни к Windows):

1. Наличие терминала и ПО, которое собственно обычно и устанавливается на сервере (обычно они не на Windows)
2. Наличие необходимых базовых компонент, которые собственно не так уж и сложно настроить для настройки, отслеживания и мониторинга локального веб-сервера
3. Логирование всех системных и пользовательских действий, в результате чего значительно проще найти причину сбоев, нежели в Windows, когда вместо внятного ответа видишь лишь адреса, в которых собственно и произошла ошибка
4. Достаточно простая настройка веб-сервера, не беря во внимания готовые сборки, которых полно на Windows, Linux сам по себе из коробки уже готов стать веб-сервером без особых заморачиванием с настройками. Если же дефолтные не подходят, то тут да - нужно курить маны и настраивать руками
5. Поднятие smtp-сервера личного тоже не трудное занятие
6. Да и как по мне для разработчика он куда удобнее, уже давно мне гораздо приятнее и уютнее работать с консолью, нежели мышкой гуи клацать для putty, генерации ключей putty и прочее производные задачи, ssh в Linux пользоваться куда удобнее
7. Из ПО я использую PhpStorm как IDE, Navicat Premium для управления БД, nginx+apache(висят на разных портах)+mysql+postgresql+mongodb+memcached+redis+postfix (как почтовый сервер) + webmin (тулза, работает как web-приложение, https://localhost:10000 для запуска, которая новичкам или людям,которые особо не хотят ковырять настройки базовых компонент, настроить все щелканьем мышки, через webmin я samba настраиваю, с конфигом как-то изначально не сложилось, нашел webmin и забил - больше не разбирался, так как особо глубоко копать не хочеелось и не хочется - работает общий доступ, настроилось, и ладно:-))

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО, NetBeans 8  более чем хватает для веб-разработчика. До 8й версии они как-то игнорировали существование хтмл5 проектов, но новая версия ИДЕ оказалась весьма удачной, особенно встроенный лайтхттп-сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Я не профессионал ещё в веб разработке, но скажу что использую: 
PHPStorm для большинства задач, или Vim для доступа по SSH если получаю какой-то простенькой заказ на фрилансе, и нужно буквально несколько файлов поправить на сервере. 
Локальную среду с нужными мне параметрами для учебы/просто побаловаться с PHP/Pythone/Node.js
разворачиваю и настраиваю на локальном ПК за 15 минут с помощью Vargant.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве IDE использую NetBeans 8 (в варианте для php).

А вот в качестве платформы использую необычное решение:
VirtualBox - в качестве виртуализатора.
Debian (32 битная версия)
Связка Apache2 + mysql + php + sudo + GuestAdditions
2 сетевых адаптора : 1й NAT, 2й виртуальный адаптер хоста
И проброшенная общая папка с кодом, которая монтируется при старте системы, расположенная в папке DropBox.

Не скажу что решение лучшее, но следующие задачи решает лучше всего:

- чистая операционная система без кучи разных ненужных сервисов (если отказаться от Netbeans в пользу Notepad++ система будет еще чище)
- возможность быстро запустить и перенастроить такую платформу (если заранее сделать настроенную резервную копию), стало возможно работать на 2х машинах
- размещение в удобном месте файлов проекта и их синхронизация